# Firebase post request Swift/SwiftUI Deprecated

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send messages using firebase cloud messaging and followed some tutorials online. Although the code works, I'm running into deprecated warnings and I'd like to fix them if possible.

Here is my code inside my swift file:

```
func sendMessageTouser(to token: String, title: String, body: String) {
       print("sendMessageTouser()")
       let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
       let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
       let paramString: [String : Any] = ["to" : token,
                                          "notification" : ["title" : title, "body" : body],
                                          "data" : ["user" : "test_id"]
       ]
       let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
       request.httpMethod = "POST"
       request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:paramString, options: [.prettyPrinted])
       request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
       request.setValue("key=\(legacyServerKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
       let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)  { (data, response, error) in
           do {
               if let jsonData = data {
                   if let jsonDataDict  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                       NSLog("Received data:\n\(jsonDataDict))")
                   }
               }
           } catch let err as NSError {
               print(err.debugDescription)
           }
       }
       task.resume()
   }
   
   func handleLogTokenTouch() {
       // [START log_fcm_reg_token]
       let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
       print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")
       // [END log_fcm_reg_token]
       self.fcmTokenMessage  = "Logged FCM token: \(token ?? "")"

       // [START log_iid_reg_token]
       InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
         if let error = error {
           print("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
         } else if let result = result {
           print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
           self.instanceIDTokenMessage  = "Remote InstanceID token: \(result.token)"
         }
       }
    
       // [END log_iid_reg_token]
   }
```

These are the 2 warnings I get at the InstanceID in the handleLogTokenTouch() Method.

1. > 'InstanceID' is deprecated: FIRInstanceID is deprecated, please use FIRInstallations for installation identifier handling and use FIRMessaging for FCM registration token handling.
2. > 'instanceID(handler:)' is deprecated: Use `Installations.installationID(completion:)` to get the app instance identifier instead. Use `Messaging.token(completion:)` to get FCM registration token instead.

What is the correct way of sending messages? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, `InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID` is deprecated and you'll need to use `Messaging.token(completion:)` to get the token.

I'd also recommend reading the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client) of Firebase Cloud
Messaging, specifically the section on [accessing the registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#fetching-the-current-registration-token). In addition to a description of how FCM works, this also contains up to date code samples that you can use, such as:

```
Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
  if let error = error {
    print("Error fetching FCM registration token: \(error)")
  } else if let token = token {
    print("FCM registration token: \(token)")
    self.fcmRegTokenMessage.text  = "Remote FCM registration token: \(token)"
  }
}
```